# In a string, how to replace a integer iteration in python?

Tags: string, loops, while-loop, append, iteration

a variable `od = str('{}'.format(data['data']['order_items'][0]))`

How can I try to integer iteration "0" in the string?

loop result as:

```
od = str('{}'.format(data['data']['order_items'][1]))
```

next

```
  od = str('{}'.format(data['data']['order_items'][2]))
    
    next 
    
    od = str('{}'.format(data['data']['order_items'][3]))
```

Thanks.

I tried:

```
od = str('{}'.format(data['data']['order_items'][0]))
index = 0
for i in range(1, 6):
    index = od.find("0", index)
    if index == -1:
        break
    od = "{}{}{}".format(od[:index], i, od[index+1:])
    index += 1
    print(od)
```

result:

```
od = str('{}'.format(data['data']['order_items'][1]))
```